# Js currying with condition

Tags: javascript, currying

im trying to understand this code for long time i know currying function but confused with this code please explain theory behind

```
var currying = function(fn) {
  var args = [];
  return function() {
    if (!!arguments.length){
      [].push.apply(args, arguments);
      return arguments.callee;
    } else {
      // what is 'this' in apply method
      return fn.apply(this, args);
    }
  }
} 

// currying var or args
// please explain the code below
var find = function(arr, el){
  return arr.indexOf(el) !== -1;
}

var newFind = currying(find)([1,2,3]);
console.log( newFind(1)());
console.log( newFind(2)());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it easier to explain, let's convert the last part of the code:

```
// newFind = currying(find)([1,2,3]);
// console.log(newFind(1)());
// above is the same with below
console.log( currying(find)([1,2,3])(1)());
```

`currying` takes a function `find` so `fn` in `currying` is `find`.
As it return a function, it can be called as it's shown on the code `currying(find)([1,2,3])`

let's look at this part, `currying(find)([1,2,3])`.
It executes the returned method of `currying`. It can access the arguments with keyword `arguments` that is the array of `[1,2,3]` on the code.

The argument is the array which means it has the length value. Then the arguments is pushed into `args` array and return its callee which means inner method of `currying`.

As it returns method again, it can be called again with next paramter `(1)` of `currying(find)([1,2,3])(1)()`.
Again, it executes the inner method of `currying` with arguments: `1`. Then it is not an array so, it calls `fn.apply(this, args)`.
`this` keyword in the code means nothing in this case. you can replace `this` to `null` or you can use `fn(...args)` instead. the code is for converting array of argumnts to each argument. e.g. `[[1,2,3], 1]` is converted to `[1,2,3], 1`
Then, finally it executes `find` function with parameter `[1,2,3]`, `1`. You should remember all this thing is from returned method of `currying` so, you must call it as a function. append `()` at the end to execute the function.

Comment: why it return false false when i log with 0 and 2 but the expecting boolean is false and true. second log is not running whats the problem

Comment: The value of variable `args` in `currying` function keeps its value when you call `currying` through `newFind`. You should call `currying` directly. e.g. `currying(find)([1,2,3])(0)()`, `currying(find)([1,2,3])(2)()`.